# Faiss GPU index cannot be serialised when passed to hugging face trainer

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-datasets

#### Describe the bug

I am working on a retrieval project and encountering I have encountered two issues in the hugging face faiss integration:

1. I am trying to pass in a dataset with a faiss index to the Huggingface trainer. The code works for a cpu faiss index, but doesn't for a gpu one, getting error:

```
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1543, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1555, in _inner_training_loop
    train_dataloader = self.get_train_dataloader()
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 831, in get_train_dataloader
    train_dataset = self._remove_unused_columns(train_dataset, description="training")
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 725, in _remove_unused_columns
    return dataset.remove_columns(ignored_columns)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 592, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 557, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py", line 481, in wrapper
    out = func(dataset, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 2146, in remove_columns
    dataset = copy.deepcopy(self)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 271, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 271, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 556, in index_getstate
    return {"this": serialize_index(self).tobytes()}
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 1607, in serialize_index
    write_index(index, writer)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py", line 9843, in write_index
    return _swigfaiss.write_index(*args)
RuntimeError: Error in void faiss::write_index(const faiss::Index*, faiss::IOWriter*) at /project/faiss/faiss/impl/index_write.cpp:590: don't know how to serialize this type of index
```

The index was created with the add_faiss_index method

```
train_dataset.add_faiss_index(
                column='embeddings',
                index_name='embeddings',
                string_factory=faiss_index_string,
                train_size=config.faiss_train_size,
                device=0,  # Use -1 for CPU, or specify GPU device ID
                faiss_verbose=True
            )
```

2. Athough faiss is written to be compatible on the gpu for searching https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Faiss-on-the-GPU I am getting error when trying to use the hugggingface code to do the search on gpu. This seems to be caused by this line https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/f9975f636542df7f95c27065ea93147440d690b7/src/datasets/search.py#L376 producing error

```
    total_scores, total_examples = self.dataset.get_nearest_examples_batch('embeddings', embeddings, k=self.k)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/search.py", line 773, in get_nearest_examples_batch
    total_scores, total_indices = self.search_batch(index_name, queries, k, **kwargs)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/search.py", line 727, in search_batch
    return self._indexes[index_name].search_batch(queries, k, **kwargs)
  File "/users/rubman/.conda/envs/protein_npt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/search.py", line 376, in search_batch
    if not queries.flags.c_contiguous:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'flags'
```

#### Environment info

huggingface Version: 2.16.1

#### Steps to reproduce the bug

```
train_dataset.add_faiss_index(
                column='embeddings',
                index_name='embeddings',
                string_factory=faiss_index_string,
                train_size=config.faiss_train_size,
                device=0,  # Use -1 for CPU, or specify GPU device ID
                faiss_verbose=True
            )
Trainer(
            model=model,
            args=args,
            train_dataset=train_dataset,
            eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
            data_collator=data_collator,
            tokenizer=tokenizer
        )
train_dataset.get_nearest_examples_batch('embeddings', embeddings, k=self.k)
```

#### Expected behavior

I would expect the faiss database code to be gpu compatible